# URL Rewrite trouble

Tags: 7, uri, iis

I have a website develop on Drupal 7 on IIS + MSSQL. I cannot update or create content when clean urls is active. The website return to edit form when i submit any change or new content.

If the cleans url is disable then the content is saved.

Please help me with this trouble.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Place the following debug statement in your index.php to debug your request:

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
debug($_GET['q']); //debug querystring
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

Now save/edit a node with and without friendly-urls.

If the values differ from each other, your rewrite-rules do not match.
If the values are the same, something else causes the problem.

If so, its hart to say, what causes the problem. One hint: page requests are GET-requests, save/edit requests are POST-requests

Comment: this sounds like a really helpful tip, upboat for you!

Comment: Hi, i try with the debug statement from larrydahooster, the debug return the node number for content pages, for admin pages return the clean url of admin page (eg. admin/config/system/site-information) but dont save / update the data and return to edit mode in the same url. If i turn off the clean urls then edit content is successfull.

firebug is returning this error when the page load :

Comment: `code` "TypeError: c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(...) is null
[Break On This Error]  

...d*)(?:n([+\-]?\d*))?/.exec(a[2]==="even"&&"2n"||a[2]==="odd"&&"2n+1"||!/\D/.test..." `code`

Really the trouble is with post whith clean url on.

Comment: So basically your Rewrite Engine Works? Your error looks like a JavaScript-error. Really strange behavior... Are you working with a Clean-Install of Drupal?

Comment: hi again, for aisle the trouble i disable the javascript on the web browser and the trouble persist. The issue is only with the POST request, because the display of pages is ok (GET requests). We have a drupal 7.2 instalation, with omega theme.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend. From [IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-drupal-on-iis):

> By default, Drupal uses query string parameters for all the URLs it
>   generates for your Web site. With the URL Rewrite Module, however, you
>   can create “clean URLs.”
>
> IIS 6.0 does not have URL rewriting capabilities, so you can use a
>   third-party URL rewriting product such as [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1599) or Ionics
>   [ISAPI Rewrite Filter](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF).
>
> IIS 7 and above have URL rewriting support, which can be enabled by
>   installing the [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module).
>
> The following instructions describe how the URL Rewrite Module for IIS
>   7 and above can be used to enable clean URLs in Drupal.
>
> 1. Open the Web.config file located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\drupal folder. If you do not have a Web.config file in the WordPress
>      directory, create it.
> 2. Copy and paste the following XML code into this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Drupal Clean URLs" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(.*)$" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                    </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> 1. Save the web.config file.

Then you can properly configure CleanURLs in drupal at `/admin/settings/clean-urls`

Comment: Hi tenken, this rules already into the web.config of my drupal website, in fact the website show pages with clean urls, the trouble is that when clean urls are active we cannot create, update content or modify settings, the website return to edit mode and don't show errors.